# One common action for all failed RestKit requests?

Tags: ios, restkit

Is it possible to set one common action for all failed requests in RestKit? I need to stop ajax spinner for those cases but I don't want to repeat this line of code in every callback (I have too many).

**UPDATE:** request example:

```
[_manager postObject:message path:@"/messages.json" parameters:nil success:^
 (RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
     Message *message = result.firstObject;
     callback(message);
 } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     failureCallback();
}];
```

And for errors I mean responses from server with status codes in 400..511 range

Comment: How are you making the requests? And failures are determined by no available mapping / HTTP error response code from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass the object manager and override each method to call `super` but wrapping the supplied failure callback in a custom block which adds your common logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in completion block of Request Operations Queue, completion block is going to call up when queue operations are failed :

```
[objectManager enqueueBatchOfObjectRequestOperations:requestOperations progress: ^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
} completion: ^(NSArray *operations) {
 //.. Stop Spinner Code

}];
```